# How do I get arm-elf-as on linux

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

A make file I'm trying to make has arm-elf-as. I've installed binutils gcc all the stuff I assumed Id need shouldnt arm-elf-as come with that? where can I get this bad boy. I see a lot of questions on here about arm-elf-gcc eabi etc. It has something to do with gnu maybe I should just install a gnu machine on a vm. Ive also googled and came up with gas or I assume gnu as and this webpage https://manned.org/arm-elf-as/f4fae7b2 but no instructions on what arm-elf-as is in. Or how to get it. Its unbuntu, project to be made   https://github.com/jeanthom/ibugger

ok I think I found what the problem is AS is in /usr/bin but

NAME ?= flasher
LS = ls.x

LIBGCC = /cygdrive/c/programme/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.1.1/libgcc.a <<

changed to LIBGCC = /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/libgcc.a but no dice.

Comment: Posting the make file might be helpful, along with OS info. As it it stands there is no context.

Comment: latest ubuntu ive tried several linux distros its an arm-elf cross compile to as CROSS  ?= arm-elf-

AS      = $(CROSS)as

CC      = $(CROSS)gcc

LD      = $(CROSS)ld

NM      = $(CROSS)nm

OBJCOPY = $(CROSS)objcopy

CFLAGS += -Os -W -Wall -ffreestanding -fomit-frame-pointer

LDFLAGS+= -T$(LS) $(LIBGCC)

Comment: OK good! I recommend editing the OP with the above comment so as to clarify the problem space.

Comment: sudo apt-get -y install gcc-arm-none-eabi binutils-arm-none-eabi (well only need the binutils if you dont want gcc.
and you can change your makefiles from arm-elf-whatever to arm-none-eabi-whatever.   alternatively you can get binutils from the gnu website and build from sources

Comment: @old_timer is there a way to not edit the make files theres tons of em like I would even rather install the operating system that can use (as) on a vm than do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply

```
sudo apt-get -y install binutils-arm-none-eabi
```

and change your makefile from arm-elf-whatever to arm-none-eabi-whatever as the arm-elf builds are a thing of the past generally.

Or you can build from sources, and I just tested this and it is okay with building arm-elf

build_arm-elf:

```
# Usage
# sudo ./build_arm-elf

# Setup vars
export TARGET=arm-elf
export PREFIX=/opt/gnuarmelf
export PATH=$PATH:$PREFIX/bin
export JN='-j 4'

export BINUVER=2.37

rm -rf build-*
rm -rf binutils-*

# Get archives
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-$BINUVER.tar.gz

# Extract archives
tar xf binutils-$BINUVER.tar.gz

# Build binutils
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-$BINUVER/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX
echo "MAKEINFO = :" >> Makefile
make $JN all
sudo make install
```

can change the BINUVER to some older version if so desired.

```
PATH=/opt/gnuarmelf/bin:$PATH
```

then you can use arm-elf-as or arm-elf-ld, etc.

Comment: LIBGCC = /cygdrive/c/programme/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.1.1/libgcc.a this is what it points to I tried  LIBGCC = /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/libgcc.a but no dice. maybe thats still the wrong one?

Comment: also since its a different compiler maybe i need to edit these to something : CROSS  ?= arm-elf-

AS      = $(CROSS)as

CC      = $(CROSS)gcc

LD      = $(CROSS)ld

NM      = $(CROSS)nm

OBJCOPY = $(CROSS)objcopy

Comment: you mentioned the gnu assembler, you need gcc as well?

Comment: depends on the specific makefiles as to how they work and if they use environment variables.....but if so then yes that would be a place to start.   this is basic programming stuff, if you are struggling here (Makefile not tool) I suspect you will struggle with the thing you are building as well.

Comment: to test that its working can I just type arm-elf-as in the terminal?

Comment: the reason im trying not to change the make files is this will eat a lot of time its a whole directory with sub directories many of them, going in and changing every make file is a pain

Comment: as shown you need the binary in the path.  I you build from sources (note you need a number of other things that you apt-get in order to be able to do that build) then with that path, yes arm-elf-as will work, try arm-elf-as --version as without anything it will either just sit there expecting input on stdin or will state there is no input file

Comment: I have spent a few hours on this now, I/you could have modified all of the makefiles by now.   If you need gnu assembler as asked, then done, answered.   If you need gcc/glibc, then you need either an early/mid gcc 4.x.x or 3.x.x, which means you need an old distro on which to build it as the compilers that are standard on the newer distros will not.  I have been trying a 16.04 in a virtual machine because I know it will build latter 4.x.x and 5.x.x for arm-none-eabi-   but still having arm-elf issues.

Comment: at this point one might need a 14.04 distro or older or build/install an older native toolchain in order to build the older cross compiler.  I dont know if I simply didnt see your libgcc line or you added it later, but that shows 4.1.1.  I am having issues with gcc 5.4.0 which is the native on this 16.04 building 4.4.7, so dont think this will build backward to 4.1.1 unless you get an older native toolchain installed.

Comment: debian/ubuntu/mint didnt start having this apt-gettable cross toolchain for arm until relatively recently, certainly not that far back gcc 4.x.x barely had thumb mode, arm was strong already then but still just growing in popularity, not like it is today.

Comment: as I may have mentioned if you are asking how to get the toolchain, you may already be in over your head. what functions need libgcc (are you doing division or other operations?)  why so many files and directories written in assembly language?  What are you planning to run this code on, etc.  are you building for bare metal (arm-none-eabi) or to run on linux (arm-linux-gnueabi).   not that libgcc should be much different since it is just covering language things and not necessarily system things, but there are still some system things in there.

Comment: its some python stuff someone wrote in like 2007 with zero documentation thats been passed around from git to git for ages for use with an ipod dumping ram sections etc. Its all linked in the top post using it in an unbuntu vm. looks like last person used cygwin. Why is it written in assembly? simple thats what reverse engineered code is. your above answer worked for arm-elf-as I assume I need a recipe for gcc to now. arm-elf-ld: error: linker script file 'ls.x' appears multiple times
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'flasher.elf' failed